# PostgreSQL query slow, what's the issue?

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql

I'm trying to store some measurement data into my postgresql db using Python Django.
So far all good, i've made a docker container with django, and another one with the postgresql server.
However, i am getting close to 2M rows in my measurement table, and queries start to get really slow, while i'm not really sure why, i'm not doing very intense queries.

This query

```
SELECT ••• FROM "measurement" WHERE "measurement"."device_id" = 26 ORDER BY "measurement"."measure_timestamp" DESC LIMIT 20
```

for example takes between 3 and 5 seconds to run, depending on which device i query.

I would expect this to run a lot faster, since i'm not doing anything fancy. 
The measurement table

```
id INTEGER
measure_timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE
sensor_height INTEGER
device_id INTEGER
```

with indices on id and measure_timestamp. 
The server doesn't look too busy, even though it's only 512M memory, i have plenty left during queries.

I configured the postgresql server with shared_buffers=256MB and work_mem=128MB.
The total database is just under 100MB, so it should easily fit. 
If i run the query in PgAdmin, i'm seeing a lot of Block I/O, so i suspect it has to read from disk, which is obviously slow.

Could anyone give me a few pointers in the right direction how to find the issue?

EDIT:
Added output of explain analyze on a query. I now added index on the device_id, which helped a lot, but i would expect even quicker query times. 
https://pastebin.com/H30JSuWa

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the query and add the results to your question. That will help giving an answer that is not based on guesses only.

Comment: Also: add the table definition to your question, including PK FK and indexes. And some discription of the data, such as cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) on `measure_timestamp` and `device_id`? If the queries always take that form, you might also like [multi-column indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-multicolumn.html).

Comment: Well i thought i did, but apparently not on device_id, so i fixed that, and it helped a lot, but i'm not there yet, i think it can get a lot faster.

Comment: Your query does an order by desc. Would you want to try creating the index also in the same fashion?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html

Comment: That did the trick, together with the other things mentioned in the answers. I wasn't aware indexes are "one way", and that i could index them descending. Querytime went from 5 seconds to 22ms. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that. You could upvote my comment if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the distribution key of your table. It is possible that the data is sparsely populated hence it affects the performance. Selecting a proper distribution key is very important when you have data of 2M records. For more details read this [on why distribution key is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550461/distributed-by-multiple-columns)